# Unable to use gradient image on background slider

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to use a gradient image to make my background slider images a little bit darker. Tried linear-gradient with the image URL but it doesn't seem to work. I have done a similar thing on the sidebar but without the gradient image and it works as you can see from the gif but it doesn't work in the background slider. Please check the gif https://media.giphy.com/media/KDbPJYlxoGN6tPEcJn/giphy.gif.

This is the code I have been using:

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-2">
      <div class="nav-sidebar">
        <div id="logo">
          <div class="logo">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/RQGBXjK/logo.png">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10 col-xl-10">
      <div class="main-content gradient">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-smoothing: antialiased;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    background: transparent;
}


.container{
    background: transparent;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

.nav-sidebar {
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: grey;
    background: linear-gradient(0deg,rgba(0,0,0,1),rgba(0,0,0,0.5)),url(https://i.ibb.co/1TBvfyP/1.jpg);
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 5px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.9), 
                0px 10px 15px 5px #000;
    z-index: 9999;
}

#logo {
    height:130px;
    width:100%;
}


.nav-sidebar #logo .logo {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.logo img{
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 10px 1px #000);
    filter: drop-shadow(5px 10px 2px #000);
}

.main-content{
    height: 100vh;
    background: black;
}


.gradient {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.9),rgba(0,0,0,0.9)),url(https://i.ibb.co/8KSjNdL/gradient.png);
    background-blend-mode: overlay;
    width:100%;
    z-index:9999;
}

.main-content{
    background-position: top 50px center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

For full code please check this codepen: https://codepen.io/zakero/pen/JjjjZMz The logo issue seems to be working in codepen but in my browser its as it is shown in the gif.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i was able to locate where the issue is,
if you inspect the HTML file you will find there's style="background: none;" added to the main-content gradient class, by removing it you will be able to display the background from the CSS file correctly.

this style were added from the JS file

```
// This element background none
original.css('background', 'none');
```

by removing it everything will be working fine.

hope this help

Comment: please mark it as a correct answer if you were able to achieve what you were looking for.
Thanks

Comment: Hey thanks for pointing it out. I removed that but it's still not working. Can you please check the css code for the gradient? If the gradient image doesn't work then it's fine to use only css to get a dark background overlay on the slider.

Comment: it's working fine now, i can see you have updated the JS file, and here's the background linear gradient from W3C

background-image: url("IMAGE_URL"), linear-gradient(#eb01a5, #d13531); /* W3C */

if you check the background URL you will find that it's only a black image (there's no effect or anything i can see on this page), so the background image is the issue here.

it's always not the same background as the one you used for the menu (https://i.ibb.co/1TBvfyP/1.jpg)

Update the URL and it should work as you expect

Comment: I can see the gradient image but it's like coming and going as the background image changes. This isn't what I am looking for. Maybe it's not possible to do it with this slider. I'll try out something else. thanks anyways. i'll choose your answer as its partially corrent.